# How do I open a worksheet in vba?

Tags: vba, worksheet

Hilariously the following code only works if the worksheet is actually selected in the excel window. I really want to finish this macro soon but can't seem to work out how to select a specific worksheet so it is open in excel? Many thanks if someone knows how. I have to use range and so on.

```
sheet.Range(Cells(firstRow, 2).Address(False, False), Cells(lastRow, 50)).Select
With Selection
    .Copy
End With
sheet.Range(Cells(firstRow, 3).Address(False, False), Cells(lastRow, 51)).Select
With Selection
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
End With
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can activate the worksheet by name or by 1-based index (the number -- 1st workbook, 2nd, and so on). The syntax is the same, either way.

This will activate the 3rd worksheet:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(3).Activate
```

This will activate the worksheet named stats:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("stats").Activate
```

Of course, you don't have to actually make the worksheet selected in the Excel window to work with it. Your code uses a variable called `sheet`, which I assume you've assigned to the active worksheet. Instead of doing that, you can `set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("stats")`, and then work with the sheet even if is not in view.

Answer (score 1):

Workbooks(x).Worksheets(x).Activate ?